# find the numerical integration of points in c#

Tags: c#, point, numerical, integrate

i have some points in c# (not definite function) and i need to numerically integrate them(prefer to e trapezoidal). is there any library or function to do that?
i see OnClosedInterval of Math.Net but it needs definite function.
(Note: it is possile to create an interpolation between points as a function and give it to OnClosedInterval but i need to know is there any library to do integral numerically stright.)

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?
You have points sampled on a curve in x/y and want to compute the integral under the curve with the trapezoidal rule between the first and the last point.

```
//assuming Point has x and y component, and array is sorted according to x
Point[] points = ...;

float integral = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<points.length; i++)
    integral += (points[i].y + points[i-1].y) / 2 * (points[i].x - points[i-1].x);
```

Of course you could also write a linear interpolation function between your points, and then give it Math.Net to integrate it. But that would be quite inefficient as it blindly samples your function and tries to find meaningful sample points, which are nothing more than your points to begin with. So by doing this (very simple) integration yourself, you can easily benefit of your knowledge about the linearly interpolated function.